# How do I create a geoJSON layer with a div icon instead of the leaflet standard icon?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to load a geoJSON layer with [div icons](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#divicon), since they are supposed to be more lightweight.

My problem is that I cannot get the divIcons to display.  The geoJSON object is stored as `individualPoints`.  I've tried styling the icon directly:

```
var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'my-div-icon'});

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {icon: myIcon});
map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer); //shows standard icon
```

and styling the icon on each layer:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.setIcon(myIcon);
    }
}); 
map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer); // nothing displays
```

and even creating an additional marker, and adding that to the map:

```
// create object to save markers
var markersID = [];

// exchanges latitude & longitude
function switchLatLong(oldLocation) {
    return new L.LatLng(oldLocation[1], oldLocation[0]);
}

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // make a marker and add to map individually
        markersID[feature.properties.id] = L.marker(switchLatLong(feature.geometry.coordinates),{icon: myIcon});
        map.addLayer(markersID[feature.properties.id]); //nothing displays on map
    }
});
```

The first code snippet shows the standard leaflet icon; the second and third snippets do not display anything.

**Question: How does one load a geoJson using divIcon?**

---

**Edit:**
Using the `new` keyword on the second and third snippets displays the divIcon, but this doesn't work in the first code snippet.  Also, I would still like to have the divIcon appear without iterating through the layers to generate a new marker.  **Also, why must the new keyword be used?**

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // set icon to a new DivIcon
        layer.setIcon(new L.DivIcon());
    }
}); 
map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer); // divIcon displays on map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to Set a DivIcon, you should know that it can be applied only to Markers.

The [GeoJSON docs](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) Say:

> Points are handled differently than polylines and polygons. By default
>   simple markers are drawn for GeoJSON Points. We can alter this by
>   passing a pointToLayer function in a GeoJSON options object when
>   creating the GeoJSON layer. This function is passed a LatLng and
>   should return an instance of ILayer, in this case likely a Marker or
>   CircleMarker.

You can use the following code to set your custom div icon, like this

```
    var myIcon = L.divIcon({ 
        iconSize: new L.Point(25, 25), 
        className: 'my-div-icon'
    });

    var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: myIcon});
            }
        }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you; this was exactly what I wanted to know. :) Oddly, while your answer works well for a small data set (10 data points), it doesn't load for me with a large data set with 10k data points.  The other method still works for the large data set (creating a `new L.DivIcon()` for each feature via `onEachFeature`).  Maybe what I did was explicitly create a layer for each point?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add this as an answer, because it works.  I'm still interested in finding out why I seem to need to create a new DivIcon each time, or if there's a more straightforward way to do this...

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        // set icon to a new DivIcon
        layer.setIcon(new L.DivIcon());
    }
}); 
map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer); // divIcon displays on map
```

Comment: You need to do it for each feature, because Leaflet create a new layer for each feature. The `geoJsonLayer` in your case is a GroupLayer consisting of Layers.

Comment: Thank you.  But why can't I just refer to the predefined icon?  Why must each layer have its own icon?